# What were the protections for tenants in California during covid-19 eviction moratorium? Where should one contact in case of protection was violated?

Tags: united-states, california, covid-19, eviction

What were the protections for tenants in California during covid-19 eviction moratorium? Where should one contact in case of protection was violated?

Comment: Relevant might be, that the moratorium ran until June 2022. Also relevant might be the statute of limitations set in California Civil Procedure Code ( https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayexpandedbranch.xhtml?tocCode=CCP&division=&title=2.&part=2.&chapter=&article= ).

Answer (score 0):

[The program expired in 2022](https://www.courts.ca.gov/44660.htm?rdeLocaleAttr=en#:%7E:text=The%20law%20provided%20protections%20for,%2D19%2Drelated%20financial%20distress.), but back then you submitted your [application](https://housing.ca.gov/contact.html) via the official [California House is Key website](https://housing.ca.gov/). The state also created an [official website](https://covid19.ca.gov/housing-and-homelessness/) for people whose housing situation was impacted by the 2020 pandemic.